# Fit image height and center horizontally inside CircleImageView in Android Studio

Tags: xml, image, android-studio, android-imageview, centering

I have a CircleImageView (using hdodenhof's CircleImageView library [here](https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView)) that is 80x80 dp, and I have a Drawable image that has 2/1 aspect ratio so it's, say, 1000x500 px.

I need to fit the image so that it's height fits the ImageView, and then center it horizontally inside the ImageView, I would like to do it entirely in XML, without using Kotlin (or Java) if possible. with the following code:

```
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/picElement"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:src="@drawable/default_element"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp" />
```

I have a result similar to this rapresentation:

[image]

But I need to have a result as the following:

[image]

So far, I've tried the following parameters found around the internet:

```
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:scaleType="centerCrop"
android:adjustViewBounds="true"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
```

But no success. One thing I noticed is that these parameters requires that either one of `android:layout_width` or `android:layout_height` (or both) should be equal to `wrap_content`, but I need the ImageView to have fixed squared size as stated above (80x80 dp).

Thank you!